# Align by decimals separately

Tags: tables, align

I have got this result. The numbers are aligned by decimals in the whole column, but I want the numbers in last three rows "Observations", "Log lik.", "Chi-squared" also aligned by decimals but not with rows above them. Also, is there a way to force the text in footnote size in paper size? Much appreciated in advance! 
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
    \small
    \sisetup{input-symbols = {()},
        table-space-text-post=*** ,
        table-align-text-post=false}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \caption{Demographic Factors for SR1 (Pooled Sample) \label{tab:pooledsr1}}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\hspace{6pt}\extracolsep{\fill}}
            l
            S[table-format=-1.5]
            *{5}{S[table-format=-2.3]
            }
            @{}}
        \toprule
        \makecell{Dependent Variable}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{SR1dummy}&\multicolumn{5}{c}{SR1}\\
        \cmidrule(l){1-1} \cmidrule{2-2} \cmidrule(l){3-7}
        Model&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Probit}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Tobit}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Cragg's}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Heckman}\\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-5}
        & &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Latent}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Censored}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Truncated} \\

        \midrule
        LnInc               &       0.254\sym{***}&       29.56\sym{***}&       20.57\sym{***}&       14.47\sym{***}&       14.89\sym{***}&       14.35\sym{***}\\
        &   (0.00521)         &     (0.628)         &     (0.406)         &     (0.287)         &     (0.514)         &     (0.661)         \\
        \addlinespace
        Age                 &     0.00448         &       0.472\sym{*}  &       0.328\sym{*}  &       0.231\sym{*}  &       0.155         &       0.162         \\
        &   (0.00287)         &     (0.259)         &     (0.180)         &     (0.127)         &     (0.194)         &     (0.157)         \\
        \addlinespace
        Kid                 &      0.0347\sym{***}&       2.180\sym{**} &       1.517\sym{**} &       1.067\sym{**} &      -0.685         &      -0.150         \\
        &    (0.0105)         &     (0.988)         &     (0.687)         &     (0.483)         &     (0.774)         &     (0.623)         \\
        \addlinespace
        Old                 &      0.0266\sym{**} &       1.158         &       0.806         &       0.567         &      -0.854         &      -0.420         \\
        &    (0.0126)         &     (1.167)         &     (0.812)         &     (0.571)         &     (0.901)         &     (0.719)         \\
        \addlinespace
        HHsize              &     -0.0430\sym{***}&      -3.580\sym{***}&      -2.491\sym{***}&      -1.753\sym{***}&      -0.578         &      -0.883\sym{**} \\
        &   (0.00623)         &     (0.577)         &     (0.401)         &     (0.282)         &     (0.440)         &     (0.374)         \\
        \addlinespace
        Male                &     0.00322         &       1.366         &       0.951         &       0.669         &       1.692\sym{*}  &       1.366\sym{*}  \\
        &    (0.0131)         &     (1.196)         &     (0.832)         &     (0.586)         &     (0.912)         &     (0.726)         \\
        \addlinespace
        Married             &     -0.0585\sym{***}&      -8.688\sym{***}&      -6.045\sym{***}&      -4.253\sym{***}&      -6.431\sym{***}&      -5.727\sym{***}\\
        &    (0.0222)         &     (2.006)         &     (1.396)         &     (0.982)         &     (1.505)         &     (1.206)         \\
        \addlinespace
        Party               &     -0.0324\sym{*}  &      -2.104         &      -1.464         &      -1.030         &      0.0964         &      -0.254         \\
        &    (0.0175)         &     (1.542)         &     (1.073)         &     (0.755)         &     (1.127)         &     (0.917)         \\
        \addlinespace
        Job                 &      0.0803\sym{***}&       10.61\sym{***}&       7.380\sym{***}&       5.192\sym{***}&       6.184\sym{***}&       5.624\sym{***}\\
        &    (0.0158)         &     (1.503)         &     (1.044)         &     (0.734)         &     (1.197)         &     (0.948)         \\
        \addlinespace
        House               &     -0.0286         &      -4.952\sym{***}&      -3.445\sym{***}&      -2.424\sym{***}&      -4.829\sym{***}&      -4.087\sym{***}\\
        &    (0.0209)         &     (1.917)         &     (1.334)         &     (0.938)         &     (1.464)         &     (1.174)         \\
        \addlinespace
        Age 30-34           &     -0.0998\sym{***}&      -7.547\sym{***}&      -5.251\sym{***}&      -3.694\sym{***}&     -0.0971         &      -1.095         \\
        &    (0.0323)         &     (2.880)         &     (2.003)         &     (1.410)         &     (2.136)         &     (1.757)         \\
        \addlinespace
        Age 35-39           &     -0.0873\sym{**} &      -9.292\sym{***}&      -6.465\sym{***}&      -4.549\sym{***}&      -3.322         &      -3.478         \\
        &    (0.0396)         &     (3.532)         &     (2.457)         &     (1.729)         &     (2.627)         &     (2.120)         \\
        \addlinespace
        Age 40-44           &      -0.117\sym{**} &      -13.26\sym{***}&      -9.224\sym{***}&      -6.490\sym{***}&      -5.429\sym{*}  &      -5.348\sym{**} \\
        &    (0.0491)         &     (4.416)         &     (3.073)         &     (2.162)         &     (3.293)         &     (2.665)         \\
        \addlinespace
        Age 45-49           &      -0.111\sym{*}  &      -10.86\sym{*}  &      -7.558\sym{*}  &      -5.318\sym{*}  &      -2.888         &      -3.287         \\
        &    (0.0623)         &     (5.610)         &     (3.904)         &     (2.746)         &     (4.185)         &     (3.387)         \\
        \addlinespace
        Age 50-59           &     -0.0563         &      -2.961         &      -2.060         &      -1.449         &       2.488         &       1.620         \\
        &    (0.0820)         &     (7.395)         &     (5.146)         &     (3.620)         &     (5.522)         &     (4.456)         \\
        \midrule
        Observations        &        5446         &        5446         &        5446         &        5446         &        3395         &        5446         \\
        Log lik.            &     -2632.3         &    -18083.2         &    -18083.2         &    -18083.2         &    -15061.6         &                     \\
        Chi-squared         &      1950.0         &      2815.1         &      2815.1         &      2815.1         &       998.9         &       315.4         \\
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses; The marginal effects in the Tobit model for latent, censored, and truncated dependent variables are listed together; provincial fixed effects controlled}\\
        \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.1\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions and observations:

- Since the numbers in the final three rows are not related to either the preceding material or to each other, decimal-aligning those numbers makes little sense. In fact, decimal-aligning the numbers might create the false impression that the numbers are somehow related to each other. I would just center them.
- I would use the machinery of the `dcolumn` package here; using the facilities of the `siunitx` package feels like overkill.
- Under no circumstance should you use the directive `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}`. If the table won't fit on a page, switch to a `longtable` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,dcolumn,makecell}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\caption{Demographic Factors for SR1 (Pooled Sample)} 
\label{tab:pooledsr1}    
\begin{tabular}{@{}l  *{5}{d{2.6}} d{2.5} @{}}
\toprule
\makecell{Dependent\\ Variable} &\mc{\makecell{SR1\\dummy}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{SR1}\\
\cmidrule{3-7}
Model
&\mc{Probit} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Tobit} &\mc{Cragg's} &\mc{Heckman}\\
\cmidrule{3-5}
&& \mc{Latent}&\mc{Censored}&\mc{Trunc.} \\

\midrule
LnInc     &   0.254\sym{***}& 29.56\sym{***}& 20.57\sym{***}& 14.47\sym{***}& 14.89\sym{***}& 14.35\sym{***}\\
          &   (0.00521)     & (0.628)       & (0.406)       & (0.287)       & (0.514)       & (0.661)   \\
\addlinespace
Age       & 0.00448         &   0.472\sym{*}& 0.328\sym{*}  & 0.231\sym{*}  & 0.155         &   0.162   \\
          &   (0.00287)     & (0.259)       & (0.180)       & (0.127)       & (0.194)       & (0.157)   \\
\addlinespace
Kid       &  0.0347\sym{***}& 2.180\sym{**} & 1.517\sym{**} & 1.067\sym{**} &      -0.685   &  -0.150   \\
          &(0.0105)         & (0.988)       & (0.687)       & (0.483)       & (0.774)       & (0.623)   \\
\addlinespace
Old       &  0.0266\sym{**} & 1.158         &   0.806       &   0.567       &  -0.854       &  -0.420   \\
          &(0.0126)         & (1.167)       & (0.812)       & (0.571)       & (0.901)       & (0.719)   \\
\addlinespace
HHsize    & -0.0430\sym{***}&-3.580\sym{***}&-2.491\sym{***}&-1.753\sym{***}&      -0.578   &  -0.883\sym{**} \\
          &   (0.00623)     & (0.577)       & (0.401)       & (0.282)       & (0.440)       & (0.374)   \\
\addlinespace
Male      & 0.00322         &   1.366       &   0.951       &   0.669       &   1.692\sym{*}& 1.366\sym{*}  \\
          &(0.0131)         & (1.196)       & (0.832)       & (0.586)       & (0.912)       & (0.726)   \\
\addlinespace
Married   & -0.0585\sym{***}&-8.688\sym{***}&-6.045\sym{***}&-4.253\sym{***}&-6.431\sym{***}&-5.727\sym{***}\\
          &(0.0222)         & (2.006)       & (1.396)       & (0.982)       & (1.505)       & (1.206)   \\
\addlinespace
Party     & -0.0324\sym{*}  &      -2.104   &  -1.464       &  -1.030       &  0.0964       &  -0.254   \\
          &(0.0175)         & (1.542)       & (1.073)       & (0.755)       & (1.127)       & (0.917)   \\
\addlinespace
Job       &  0.0803\sym{***}& 10.61\sym{***}& 7.380\sym{***}& 5.192\sym{***}& 6.184\sym{***}& 5.624\sym{***}\\
          &(0.0158)         & (1.503)       & (1.044)       & (0.734)       & (1.197)       & (0.948)   \\
\addlinespace
House     & -0.0286         &-4.952\sym{***}&-3.445\sym{***}&-2.424\sym{***}&-4.829\sym{***}&-4.087\sym{***}\\
          &(0.0209)         & (1.917)       & (1.334)       & (0.938)       & (1.464)       & (1.174)   \\
\addlinespace
Age 30--34&-0.0998\sym{***} &-7.547\sym{***}&-5.251\sym{***}&-3.694\sym{***}&-0.0971        &  -1.095   \\
          &(0.0323)         & (2.880)       & (2.003)       & (1.410)       & (2.136)       & (1.757)   \\
\addlinespace
Age 35--39 & -0.0873\sym{**}&-9.292\sym{***}&-6.465\sym{***}&-4.549\sym{***}&-3.322         &  -3.478   \\
           &(0.0396)        & (3.532)       & (2.457)       & (1.729)       & (2.627)       & (2.120)   \\
\addlinespace
Age 40--44 &  -0.117\sym{**}&-13.26\sym{***}&-9.224\sym{***}&-6.490\sym{***}&-5.429\sym{*}  &-5.348\sym{**} \\
           &(0.0491)        & (4.416)       & (3.073)       & (2.162)       & (3.293)       & (2.665)   \\
\addlinespace
Age 45--49 &  -0.111\sym{*} &-10.86\sym{*}  &-7.558\sym{*}  &-5.318\sym{*}  &    -2.888     &  -3.287   \\
           &(0.0623)        & (5.610)       & (3.904)       & (2.746)       & (4.185)       & (3.387)   \\
\addlinespace
Age 50--59 & -0.0563     &  -2.961     &  -2.060     &  -1.449     &   2.488     &   1.620   \\
           &(0.0820)     & (7.395)     & (5.146)     & (3.620)     & (5.522)     & (4.456)   \\
\midrule
Observations  &  \mc{5446}     &  \mc{5446}      & \mc{5446}       &  \mc{5446}      &  \mc{3395}      &  \mc{5446}   \\
Log lik.      & \mc{$-2632.3$} &  \mc{$-18083.2$}& \mc{$-18083.2$} &  \mc{$-18083.2$}&  \mc{$-15061.6$}&  \\
Chi-squared   &  \mc{1950.0}   &  \mc{2815.1}    & \mc{2815.1}     &  \mc{2815.1}    &  \mc{998.9}     &  \mc{315.4}   \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{7}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses; The marginal 
effects in the Tobit model for latent, censored, and truncated dependent variables are listed 
together; provincial fixed effects controlled.}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.1\); \sym{**} \(p<0.05\); \sym{***} \(p<0.01\).}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

- for different column formatting for last three row of table you need to split table into two parts and for each determine column parameters
- to preserve uniform columns spread corresponding columns had to have equal width
- your request is unusual, far more simple is usual used solution at such tables as proposed *Mico* in his answer

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, ltablex, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
    \small
    \sisetup{input-symbols = {()},% changed
       group-four-digits,
        table-align-text-post=false}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \caption{Demographic Factors for SR1 (Pooled Sample) \label{tab:pooledsr1}}
   \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
            p{14ex}
            S[table-format=-1.5,% changed
              table-space-text-post={***}]
       *{5}{S[table-format=-2.3,% changed
              table-space-text-post={***}]}
                                }
    \toprule
\makecell{Dependent\\Variable}% changed
    &   {\makecell{SR1\\dummy}}% changed
        &   \multicolumn{5}{c}{SR1}                                 \\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-7}% changed
\multirow{2}{*}{Model}% changed
    &   {\multirow{2}{*}{Probit}}% changed
        &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Tobit}
            &   {\multirow{2}{*}{Cragg's}}
                &   {\multirow{2}{*}{Heckman}}                      \\% changed
        \cmidrule(lr){3-5}% changed
    &   &   {\makecell{Latent}}
            &   {\makecell{Censored}}
                &   {\makecell{Truncated}}
                    &   &                                           \\% changed
        \midrule
LnInc   &   0.254\sym{***}  &   29.56\sym{***}  &   20.57\sym{***}
    &   14.47\sym{***}  &   14.89\sym{***}  &   14.35\sym{***}      \\
        &   (0.00521)       &   (0.628)         &   (0.406)
    &   (0.287)         &   (0.514)         &   (0.661)             \\
        \addlinespace
Age     &   0.00448         &   0.472\sym{*}    &   0.328\sym{*}
    &   0.231\sym{*}    &   0.155           &   0.162               \\
        &   (0.00287)       &   (0.259)         &   (0.180)
    &   (0.127)         &   (0.194)         &   (0.157)             \\
        \addlinespace
Kid     &   0.0347\sym{***} &   2.180\sym{**}   &   1.517\sym{**}
    &   1.067\sym{**}       &   -0.685      &   -0.150              \\
        &    (0.0105)         &     (0.988)         &     (0.687)
    &     (0.483)       &   (0.774)         &   (0.623)             \\
        \addlinespace
Old     &   0.0266\sym{**}  &   1.158           &   0.806
    &   0.567           &   -0.854          &   -0.420              \\
        &    (0.0126)       &   (1.167)         &   (0.812)
    &   (0.571)         &   (0.901)         &   (0.719)             \\
        \addlinespace
HHsize  &   -0.0430\sym{***}&   -3.580\sym{***} &   -2.491\sym{***}
    &   -1.753\sym{***} &   -0.578          &   -0.883\sym{**}      \\
        &   (0.00623)       &     (0.577)       &     (0.401)
    &     (0.282)       &   (0.440)         &   (0.374)             \\
        \addlinespace
Male    &   0.00322         &   1.366           &   0.951         
    &   0.669           &   1.692\sym{*}    &   1.366\sym{*}        \\
        &    (0.0131)       &   (1.196)         &   (0.832)         
    &   (0.586)         &   (0.912)         &   (0.726)             \\
        \addlinespace
Married &   -0.0585\sym{***}&   -8.688\sym{***} &   -6.045\sym{***}
    &   -4.253\sym{***} &   -6.431\sym{***} &   -5.727\sym{***}     \\
        &   (0.0222)        &   (2.006)         &   (1.396)         
    &   (0.982)         &   (1.505)         &   (1.206)             \\
        \addlinespace
Party   &   -0.0324\sym{*}  &   -2.104          &   -1.464         
    &   -1.030          &   0.0964          &   -0.254              \\
        &    (0.0175)       &   (1.542)         &   (1.073)         
    &   (0.755)         &   (1.127)         &   (0.917)             \\
        \addlinespace
Job     &   0.0803\sym{***} &   10.61\sym{***}  &   7.380\sym{***}
    &   5.192\sym{***}  &   6.184\sym{***}  &   5.624\sym{***}      \\
        &    (0.0158)       &   (1.503)         &   (1.044)         
    &   (0.734)         &   (1.197)         &   (0.948)             \\
        \addlinespace
House   &   -0.0286         &   -4.952\sym{***} &   -3.445\sym{***}
    &   -2.424\sym{***} &   -4.829\sym{***} &   -4.087\sym{***}     \\
        &    (0.0209)       &   (1.917)         &   (1.334)         
    &   (0.938)         &   (1.464)         &   (1.174)             \\
        \addlinespace
Age 30-34   &   -0.0998\sym{***}    &   -7.547\sym{***} &   -5.251\sym{***}
    &   -3.694\sym{***} &   -0.0971     &   -1.095                  \\
        &   (0.0323)         &  (2.880)         &   (2.003)         
    &   (1.410)         &   (2.136)         &   (1.757)             \\
        \addlinespace
Age 35-39   &   -0.0873\sym{**}     &   -9.292\sym{***} &   -6.465\sym{***}
    &   -4.549\sym{***} &   -3.322          &   -3.478              \\
        &   (0.0396)        &  (3.532)          &   (2.457)         
    &   (1.729)         &   (2.627)         &   (2.120)             \\
        \addlinespace
Age 40-44   &   -0.117\sym{**}      &   -13.26\sym{***} &   -9.224\sym{***}
    &   -6.490\sym{***}     &      -5.429\sym{*}    &   -5.348\sym{**}  \\
        &    (0.0491)               &   (4.416)         &   (3.073)         
    &   (2.162)             &   (3.293)     &   (2.665)                 \\
        \addlinespace
Age 45-49   &   -0.111\sym{*}       &   -10.86\sym{*}   &   -7.558\sym{*}  
    &   -5.318\sym{*}       &   -2.888              &   -3.287         \\
        &    (0.0623)               &   (5.610)         &   (3.904)         
    &   (2.746)             &   (4.185)             &   (3.387)         \\
        \addlinespace
Age 50-59   &   -0.0563             &   -2.961          &   -2.060         
    &   -1.449              &   2.488               &   1.620           \\
        &   (0.0820)                &   (7.395)         &   (5.146)         
    &   (3.620)             &   (5.522)             &   (4.456)         \\
        \midrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}% added separate table for last three rows
            p{14ex}
            S[table-format=-4.2]
       *{4}{S[table-format=-5.2]}
            S[table-format=4.1] 
            }

Observations    &   5446    &   5446        &   5446        &   5446         
    &   3395        &   5446                \\
Log lik.        &   -2632.3 &   -18083.2    &   -18083.2    &    -18083.2
    &   -15061.6    &                       \\
Chi-squared     &   1950.0  &   2815.1      &   815.1       &   2815.1         
    &   998.9       &   315.4               \\
        \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]% changed
    \multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses; The marginal effects in the Tobit model for latent, censored, and truncated dependent variables are listed together; provincial fixed effects controlled}\\
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.1\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I run the code, the last three rows went to the right to the main table?

Comment: I wouldn't group the decimals in groups of three. In addition, I'd say it's highly questionable to align the number of observations (a positive integer), the log-likelihood (some real number), and the chi-squared test statistics (some positive real number) on their implied decimal markers; doing so inevitably creates the impression that those numbers are somehow related to each other -- which is obviously not the case.

Comment: I just do, what OP request and haven't any intention to interfere in table design :). However,  your comment is helpful ...

Comment: @JustinJunfeiZhu, unfortunately the first provided MWE was damaged by later added comments. Now this is corrected and table design is slightly improved. See and test if now better fit to your request.

Comment: Many thanks! I just incorporated some codes of yours. It is truly helpful.

Comment: @JustinJunfeiZhu, than you can up-vote my answer, and of course of *Mico*, (accepted one) too :). Anyway, in my answer I strictly follow your request in question ...